# Отображение блока и скрытие блока по нажатию одной кнопки

Tags: javascript

Пишу впервые и очень надеюсь получить помощь.
У меня есть блок. Цель блока, получение ответа на часто задаваемые вопросы. В этом блоке написан сам вопрос и есть иконка в виде знака "+" При нажатии на эту иконку появляется блок с ответом на данный вопрос. Все работает, однако если добавить вторые два блока(вопрос + ответ), то при нажатии на один из плюсов открывается два блока с ответами.

```js
const faqBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-fi");
const faqBodys = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-body");
const faqBtn = document.querySelector(".faq-fi");
const faqBody = document.querySelector(".faq-body");
faqBtns.forEach(faqBtn => {
  faqBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    faqBodys.forEach(faqBody => {
      if (faqBody.style.display == "none") {
        faqBtn.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        faqBody.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        faqBtn.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
        faqBody.style.display = "none";
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<section class="faq-box">
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Цена на товар указана с учетом НДС?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Цена указана уже с НДС</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Как рассчитывается стоимость доставки?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Стоимость доставки. Бла бла бла.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

При нажатии на один из плюсов открывается два блока с ответами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу вот такой вариант решения с использованием делегирования событий... Обработчик один, на родителе. Именно он и решает задачу "Вкл/Выкл" нужного элемента.

```js
// навешиваю обработчик клика на родительский элемент
document.querySelector(".faq-box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  // определяю элемент на котором произошло событие клика
  let o = e.target
  // если это не тот элемент - заканчиваю обработку
  if (!o.closest('.faq-fi')) return
  // определяю нужного мне родителя
  o = o.closest('.faq-header')
  // определяю следующий за ним элемент
  o = o.nextElementSibling
  // добавляю или удаляю класс on
  o.classList.toggle('on')
})
```

```css
.faq-body {
  display: none;
}
.faq-body.on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="faq-box">
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Цена на товар указана с учетом НДС?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi">+</i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Цена указана уже с НДС</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Как рассчитывается стоимость доставки?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi">+</i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Стоимость доставки. Бла бла бла.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Приветствую. Благодарю. Это действительно работает, однако я не могу понять код. Если Вас не затруднит. Могли бы вы объяснить за что отвечает каждая строка?

Comment: @Elrate, я написал комментарии к каждой строке... Но если ты не понимаешь такой простой алгоритм - это значит что ты сам JS совсем не изучал. И вполне возможно мои объяснения тебе не особо помогут...

Comment: благодарю за комментарии. Js изучаю не так давно, с такими методами не был знаком, до твоего решения. Благодарю ещё раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
faqBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    faqBodys.forEach(faqBody => {
        ...
    })
})
```

У вас в коде указано, что при клике на иконку нужно по всем `.faq-body` пройтись, поэтому у вас открывается все. Если вы хотите сохранить текущую разметку, вам необходимо обращаться только к элементу с таким же индексом массиве `faqBodys`, как у текущего `faqBtn`.

Пример, как это можно сделать:

```js
const faqBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-fi");
const faqBodys = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-body");
faqBtns.forEach((faqBtn, faqBtnKey) => {
  faqBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (faqBodys[faqBtnKey].style.display == "none") {
        this.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
        faqBodys[faqBtnKey].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        this.style.transform = "rotate(0)";
        faqBodys[faqBtnKey].style.display = "none";
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<section class="faq-box">
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Цена на товар указана с учетом НДС?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi">+</i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Цена указана уже с НДС</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-header">
    <h4 class="faq-heading">Как рассчитывается стоимость доставки?</h4>
    <i class="fi fi-rr-cross faq-fi">+</i>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body">
    <p class="faq-text">Стоимость доставки. Бла бла бла.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```